# Returning only part of an array field in a Mongodb collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a very simple test collection in a Mongodb database. One item in that collection looks like the following:

```
_id: ObjectId()
name: test
data: an array of 6 elements
```

What I would like to do, for example, is return just 2 elements of the array "data". How do I do this?

I found a similar question on here but couldn't get the answer to work.

Comment: elements are objects or just number or string. Would be nice if you can paste some sample data. And what you have tried so far.

Comment: Which element to return? 2 first, last, by index, by value??

Answer (score 0):

**Sample data:**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5bd9f112f255307d51f3257a"),
  "name" : "foo",
  "data" : [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 ]
}
```

**Aggregation:** Check [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HefVmczbjvx)

```
db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([
  {$match: {name: "foo"}},
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$match: {data: {$gt: 4}}},
  {$group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    name: {$first: "$name"},
    data: {$push: "$data"}
  }}
]);
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5bd9f112f255307d51f3257a"),
  "name" : "foo",
  "data" : [ 5, 6 ]
}
```

**Steps:**

1. `$match` to filter some unwanted document first.
2. `$unwind` array to object.
3. `$match` again to check condition on array elements which are no converted as a sperate object.
4. `$group` again creating a same single document but we will now push those filtered array element and make it again as an array.

Comment: This isn't what I am looking for but it is a great answer. I appreciate the effort. Using your sample data, I don't want to return elements that are greater than a certain value. What I want to do is be able to specify a range of elements by their index that I want to return. So some way of saying, for example, return the first 3 elements (i.e. values 1,2,4) or the elements in positions 2 and 3 (i.e. values 4,5)